# In SQL , how to build a loop that copies a row number of times

Tags: sql

could someone please help? My starting table looks like this with 2 fields:

```
Name    Counter
dave    2
Joe     3
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
Name    Counter
dave    1
dave    2
joe     1
joe     2
joe     3
```

Essentially creating n number of records base on the counter and starts at 1. I tried to do a loop using counter as a variable, but the code just runs nonstop.. could someone help?

Comment: what rdbms are you using? Also, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: can you post the loop counter

Comment: sorry it's my first time posting so I'm still trying to figure out how to create a table or format things correctly... the count for Dave is essentially 3 and Joes is 2. I am using aquadata studio (which should be exactly the same as sql) and Sybase is the rdbms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A procedural SQL Server solution:

```
declare @input table
(
  name nvarchar(100)
 ,wantedrows int
 ,processed bit
 ,id uniqueidentifier
);

declare @output table
(
  name nvarchar(100)
 ,rownum int
);

insert into @input
select 'Dave',3,0,newid()
union
select 'Joe',2,0,newid();

while exists(select * from @input where processed = 0)
begin
  declare @currentid uniqueidentifier = (select top 1 id from @input where processed = 0);
  declare @currentwantedrows int = (select wantedrows from @input where id = @currentid);
  declare @i int = 0;
  while @i < @currentwantedrows
  begin
    insert into @output
    select name,@i+1
    from @input
    where id = @currentid;
    set @i = @i + 1;
  end;
  update @input set processed = 1 where id = @currentid;
end

select name,wantedrows from @input;
select * from @output;
```

Comment: This code is actually relatively similar to what i wrote! Based on what you have i tweaked my code and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number-table or following trick using a system view to build a sequence:

```
WITH Nums AS
(
  SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_objects 

)
SELECT Name, Counter = n
FROM Nums n CROSS JOIN Table1 t1
WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND Counter
ORDER BY Name, Counter;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/053eb/5/0)</kbd>

This view has only about 2000 rows, so if you need more you could use a number-table.

http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

( presuming SQL-Server )

Comment: Thanks for your help! Tried to run the code, got an error all_objects not found :(

Comment: @Dave: probably you are not using sql-server, are you?

Comment: I'm using aquadata interface.. is there a difference.. haha

Answer (score 0):

Is a hundred copies enough?

```
create table #c (num)

insert into #c (num)
select 0 union
select 1 union
select 2 union
select 3 union
select 4 union
select 5 union
select 6 union
select 7 union
select 8 union
select 9

select T.Name,  c1.num * 10 + c0.num + 1
from T, #c c1, #c c0
where c1.num * 10 + c0.num < T.Counter

drop table #c
```

You didn't say which version of Sybase. The old ones I've worked on didn't allow derived tables so I had to throw the values into a temp table. But you can see how to extend the idea. This may not be the best approach if this is something you need to do more than once though.

Comment: Hi Shawn, it could be more than 9 in the table i have.